# Distributed OSGI in Karaf -Consumer service not starting

Tags: osgi, apache-zookeeper, apache-karaf, karaf, dosgi

I am just starting with DOSGi in Karaff using Zookeeper. I have the service offered in an instance of Karaf and the consumer in another.
The service side works well. Once published, I can see it using the log:display command in Karaf console where the Zookeeper server is installed and I can access to the wsdl by the browser as well. 
The problem is in the consumer side. It should write a message (ref code below) when the service is up, but it never happens.
Consumer code:

```
package org.osgi.proyecto.dev.internal.consumer;


import org.osgi.proyecto.dev.consumer.IConsumer;   
import org.osgi.proyecto.dev.sensor.ISensor;

public class Consumer implements IConsumer {

public void sensorActivo(ISensor sensor){       
    System.out.println("El sensor esta activo");
}   
}
```

And the component.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0"     immediate="true" enabled="true" name="OSGI_Bundle-Consumer">
<implementation class="org.osgi.proyecto.dev.internal.consumer.Consumer"/>
<reference bind="sensorActivo" cardinality="1..1"   interface="org.osgi.proyecto.dev.sensor.ISensor" name="ISensor"  policy="dynamic"/>>
</scr:component>
```

Manifest:

```
  Manifest-Version: 1.0
  Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
  Bundle-Name: OSGI_Bundle-Consumer
  Bundle-SymbolicName: OSGI_Bundle-Consumer2
  Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
  Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
  Service-Component: OSGI-INF/component.xml
  Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="1.8.0",
   org.osgi.proyecto.dev.sensor
```

I tried  forcing the consumer bundle (start bundle) and it gives me this error:

> Error starting bundle 137: Unable to resolve OSGI_Bundle-Consumer [137](R 137.1): missing requirement [OSGI_Bundle-Consumer [137](R 137.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.proyecto.dev.sensor) Unresolved requirements: [[OSGI_Bundle-Consumer [137](R 137.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.proyecto.dev.sensor)]

It seems that there is a dependency error. This is solved installing the sensor bundle (Installed state) in the consumer instance. 
How can I avoid  installing the same sensor bundle in both Karaf instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the service interface in a separate bundle. Then you can install the consumer and the interface bundle on the consumer side and the service and the interface bundle on the server side.

Comment: Thank you Christian, now the problem is solve. Also congratulations for your tutorials.